# How do you redirect to non-www

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

am using the new Asp.Net 5 or Asp.Net Core 1.0 as they are calling it and want to route all my traffic to non-www along with making sure querystrings and folders afterwards stay intact.

with no more web.config, where am i supposed to make this change? information seems very sparse

Comment: 1) There is a web.config in the `\wwwroot` directory 2) It is unclear from your question just what you are asking (what do you mean by non-www?).

Comment: sorry, i'll try to be more clear. when someone types in my site and puts in a "http://www.[domain.com]", i want to redirect them to "http://[domain.com]". i used to do this with urlrewrite in web.config, how do i do it in the new config files? sorry for my poorly written question

Comment: If you are hosting on IIS, you can still use url rewrite because it is a feature of IIS, not ASP.NET. You just need to put your rules into `web.config`. You will need to experiment - I am not sure if putting them into `wwwroot\web.config` is the right choice or if you need to add a new `web.config` into the application root - it depends on where that `web.config` file ends up when the site is deployed. BTW - your example is not very good - all modern browsers will automatically redirect `domain.com` to `http://domain.com` so there is no need to do rewriting for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint NightOwl888 as web.config files are NOT gone in asp.net core. I apparently took that notion too literally so I added my urlrewrite code for non-www redirects into the web.config file in the /wwwroot folder and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Most config files have migrated to `.json` files now, ie `config.json`, `appsettings.json`.

Some examples:

- [asp-net-5-configuration](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/284/asp-net-5-configuration)
- [fundamentals / configuration](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html)
- [config migration](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingconfig.html)

Comment: There is still a web.config in the wwwroot folder to configure all IIS related stuff